# How to improve my implementation of an arithmetic neutral element (identity) so that it works with numpy.around?

Tags: python

### Context

So for a project I was writing some Monte Carlo code and I wanted to support both 2D coordinates and 3D coordinates. The obvious solutions were to implement either 2D and 3D versions of certain functions or to have some 'if' checking in the algorithm itself. I wanted a more elegant solution where I could just work with one algorithm capable of handling both situations. The idea I came up with was to work with some kind of neutral element '**I**' for the optional third coordinate (z-direction). It's usage is as follows: if no explicit *z* value is provided it defaults to **I**. In any case the *z* value is effectively used in the calculations but has no effect if *z* = **I**.

For example: let *a* be any number then *a* + **I** = **I** + *a* = *a*. Likewise *a* x **I** = **I** x *a* = a

For addition and multiplication these are **I** = 0 and respectively **I** = 1. It is immediately clear that any numerical value for **I** will not work. For example if I have a cost function of the form *xyz + (x +y +x)^2*.

### Implementation

Luckily, programmatically we are not constrained by mathematics to implement something like that and here's my attempt:

```
class NeutralElement:
    def __add__(self, other):
        return other

    def __sub__(self, other):
        return other

    def __mul__(self, other):
        return other

    def __truediv__(self, other):
        return other

    def __pow__(self, other):
        return self

    def __radd__(self, other):
        return other

    def __rsub__(self, other):
        return other

    def __rmul__(self, other):
        return other

    def __rtruediv__(self, other):
        return other

    def __bool__(self):
        return True

    def __getitem__(self, index):
        return self

    def __str__(self):
        return 'I'

    def __repr__(self):
        return 'I'
```

Usage is simple: `n = NeutralElement()` and you can then use `n` in whatever equation you want. The above implementation works well in the sense that the Monte Carlo algorithm finishes without problems and manages to give meaningful results. I can even construct a Numpy array of it and use it. Though it's not compatible with everything. Calling np.around on an array of it gives an error about '_rint' not implemented. Though I did manage to get it to work with `round()` and `ndarray.round()`. (Not reflected in the code above.)

### Question

<s>My question now is if there's anything I can do to improve compatibility with other functions or just improve this implementation itself. Also welcome are better alternative solutions to the problem described above.</s>

After some feedback I've attempted to narrow down the scope of my question. I would like to modify the above class so that it returns a Numpy array of strings `['I', 'I', ..., 'I']` when `numpy.around` is used on a Numpy array of `NeutralElement`s

Comment: This question is asking for general advice/suggestions. Here at SE we give specific answers to specific questions. "My question now is if there's anything I can do to improve compatibility with other functions or just improve this implementation itself" is a very general and vague question. please ask a specific question you need help with

Comment: @NathanThomas Would it be better if I reformulated it as "What's the best way of implementing such a feature?"

Comment: I think you need to start with what is wrong with the current implementation? Does it not work? Is it slow? If you can pinpoint what it is that you don't like, then you can ask a more specific question. For example: "Line X is very slow. Is there a better implementation of this?" would be a good start.

Comment: @NathanThomas I can't really come up with a more concrete question. There are some compatibility issues but I can work around them. As you can see the implementation is really trivial so it's hard for me to ask to improve specific parts and asking to improve/implement the entire feature is too broad. I will delete the question later. Thanks for the feedback.

Comment: You can make a more focused question using info in the context and the paragraph before the question section. Think about what it is that you want to achieve and then try to be as specific as possible. If you have to break it down so you only fix one small thing and then create a new question for the next specific question, that is ok. Think of it from someone else's perspective - what question/answer is likely to be useful to them also? For example, this question I wrote is targeted and specific: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28747141/populate-values-from-one-numpy-array-into-another

Comment: @NathanThomas I have narrowed the scope of the question. Is it better now?